# How can I convert Int32 to Int in Swift?

Tags: swift, core-data, int, type-conversion

It should be easy but I can only find the reverse conversion.
How can I convert Int32 to Int in Swift?
Unless the problem is different?

I have a value stored in Core Data and I want to return it as an Int.

Here is the code I am using, which does not work:

```
func myNumber () -> Int {
    var myUnit:NSManagedObject
    myUnit=self.getObject(“EntityName”) // This is working.

    return Int(myUnit.valueForKey(“theNUMBER”)?.intValue!)
 }
```

Comment: `let i32 = UInt32(911)` and then `let i = Int(i32)` hope this helps

Comment: intValue returns Int32 you can use integerValue to return Int

Comment: return myUnit.valueForKey(“theNUMBER”)?.integerValue ??  0

Comment: Replacing intValue by integerValue doesn't change much. It still doesn't work.

Comment: @Matteo Piombo: I hav tried your solution, but without success.

Comment: You should consider changing your title because atm it is not you real problem.

Comment: Now I see your added sample code. @Arbitur answers seems more appropriate now

Comment: @LeoDabus your simple solution works for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error is your ? after valueForKey.

Int initializer doesnt accept optionals.

By doing `myUnit.valueForKey(“theNUMBER”)?.intValue!` gives you an optional value and the ! at the end doesnt help it.

Just replace with this:

```
return Int(myUnit.valueForKey(“theNUMBER”)!.intValue)
```

But you could also do like this if you want it to be fail safe:

```
return myUnit.valueForKey(“theNUMBER”)?.integerValue ?? 0
```

And to shorten you function you can do this:

```
func myNumber() -> Int {
    let myUnit = self.getObject("EntityName") as! NSManagedObject

    return myUnit.valueForKey("theNUMBER")?.integerValue ?? 0
}
```

Answer (score 45):

Am I missing something or isn't this ridiculously easy?

```
let number1: Int32 = 10
let number2 = Int(number1)
```

Comment: That's very strange. It just works in my playground. What error are you getting?

Comment: If the conversion is as you write, then the problem must be different. I edited the question, in order to make things clearer. I want the function to work, I thought the problem was about conversion, but maybe it isn't.
I am only making my first steps in Swift.

Comment: Before looking at your edit, core data returns numbers as `NSNumber` if I'm correct. Usually the typical conversion `Int()` should be enough.

Comment: March23 2016; Swift 2.x works! best answer by a mile or more

Comment: `Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Int' with an argument list of type '(() -> Int32)` this is the error that im getting in swift 4

Comment: @Sarath No problems here, using Swift 4.1. `print(type(of: number2))` prints `Int` just fine.

Comment: @Eendje Thanks for your answer and I converted it into string and back to Int.  like this `Int("\(Int32value)")` its worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

Swift 4.0 producing "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Int' with an argument list of type '(() -> Int32)"

```
let number1: Int32 = 10
let number2 = Int(number1)
```

Simply do this

```
Int("\(Int32value)")
```

I'm unable to understand why swift is making things difficult.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes "?" make things twisted ,
adding "!" to Int32 and then convert it to int works

```
let number1 = someInt32!
let number2 = Int(number1)
```