# Swift 3 - convert Int32 to Int

Tags: casting, swift3, int, conditional-statements, int32

Using Swift 3 and am having problems comparing an Int32 and Int in an IF statement.

```
// myIntFromCoreData is an Int32
// kMyConstant is an Int

if myIntFromCoreData == kMyConstant // error: Binary operator "==" cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int32' and 'Int'
{
     Log("Cool")
}
```

So, I tried casting the values to Int32 or Int using:

```
myint32.intValue // Value of type 'Int32' has no member 'intValue'

myint32 as Int // Cannot convert value of type 'Int32' to type 'Int' in coercion

kMyConstant as Int32 // Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to type 'Int32' in coercion
```

But kept getting the above errors.  Can anybody provide some direction no how to handle this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30660603/3991696).

```
let number1: Int32 = 10
let number2 = Int(number1)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Thanks!